# Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the function:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<0, \\ a(b-x) & 0\le x\le b, \\ 0 & b<x, \end{cases}
$$

where $a, b ∈ (0, ∞)$. We also know that $\operatorname{E}(X) = 1$. I need to find out $a,b$ and the distribution function.

I made an equation system using $\operatorname{E}(X)=1$ and $F(X)=1$ from which I got $a = 2/9$ and $b = 3$, but I'm not really sure if my method is correct and I'm a bit lost on how to calculate the distribution function. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

$$\operatorname{E}(X)=\int_0^b y f(y) \,dy,$$
This gave me $ab^3=6$.

$$F(X)=\int_0^b f(y) \, dy$$
This gave me $ab^2=2$.

Comment: Hi Kamil Pop, and welcome to MSE. Can you post your method so we can take a look at it and give you appropriate feedback?

Comment: Hi Adam! Edited the post for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need for your density function to integrate to $1.$
According to your solution you have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 0\,dx + 
\int_0^3 \frac{2}{9}(3-x)\,dx + \int_3^\infty 0\,dx = \int_0^3 \frac{2}{9}(3-x)\,dx = 1,$$
which is correct. Then to get the mean, you need to find.
$$E(X) = \int_0^3 x \cdot \frac{2}{9}(3-x)\,dx$$
You have a random variable with support $(0,3)$ so the mean cannot possibly be $6.$  Try the integration again.

Your answer for the CDF is in three parts: $F(x) = 0,$ for $x \in (\infty,0);\;
F(x) = 1,$ for $x \in (3, \infty);$ and
$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for $x \in [0, 3].$ You still need to evaluate
the last integral. Make sure that you get $F(0) = 0$ and $F(3) = 1.$

Comment: Yup, all good! This helped a lot. Cheers! :)